# Não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro no php, mas não funciona

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Eu fiz um form de cadastro e uma query de insert com pdo, mas ao inserir o dados e apertar no botão pra chamar a query não acontece nada, não aparece mensagens de erro, nem no log, tem alguma coisa errada nos códigos ? ;-;

**Query insert**

```
class Cadastro {

    private $con;
    private $serial;
    private $login;
    private $email;
    private $rrname;
    private $senha;
    private $nome;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->con = new Conexao();
    }

    public function queryInsert($dados) {
        try {
            $this->login = $dados['login'];
            $this->senha = sha1($dados['senha']);
            $this->email = $dados['email'];
            $this->rrname = $dados['rrname'];
            $cst = $this->con->conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO 'contas' ('login', 'senha', 'email', 'nomenorr') VALUES (:login, :senha, :email, :rrname)");
            $cst->bindParam(':login', $this->login);
            $cst->bindParam(':senha', $this->senha);
            $cst->bindParam(':email', $this->email);
            $cst->bindParam(':rrname', $this->rrname);
            if ($cst->execute()) {
                return 'sucess';

            } else {
                return 'error';
            }
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {

        }
    }
```

Class de conexão

```
<?php

    class Conexao {

        private $servidor;
        private $banco;
        private $user;
        private $password;
        private static $pdo;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->servidor = "localhost";
            $this->banco = "rrcard";
            $this->user = "root";
            $this->password = "12345";
        }

        public function conectar() {
            try {
                if (is_null(self::$pdo)) {
                    self::$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->servidor . ";bdname" . $this->banco, $this->user, $this->password);
                }
                return self::$pdo;
            } catch (PDOException $ex) {

            }
        }
    }
```

**php da página htm**

```
<?php
require_once '/src/domain/conta.php';

$Cad = new Cadastro();

if (isset($_POST['btCad'])) {
    if ($Cad->queryInsert($_POST) == 'sucess') {
       header("location: ./index.php");
    } else {
       header("location: ./cadastro.php");
    }
}
?>
```

**Form de cadastro html**

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    Login:<br>
    <input type="text" name="login" class="campo" maxlength="40" required autofocus><br>
    Senha:<br>
    <input type="password" name="senha" class="campo" maxlength="40" required><br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="campo" maxlength="50" required><br>
    Nome no RR:<br>
    <input type="text" name="rrname" class="campo" maxlength="40" required><br>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="btCad" value="Confirmar" class="btn">
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="check" required>
    Ao criar a conta você confirma que leu e concorda com os nossos <a id="terms" class="terms" href="#"> termos de uso </a>
</form>
```

Comment: você não tem nem um botão chamando o action="/aquivoParaExecutarOMetodo"
<button type="submit">salvar</button>

Comment: Mas o botão que está ali já está sendo chamado no código php, então não preciso colocar um caminho no action="", não ?

Comment: Já cogitou em exibir alguma mensagem quando uma exceção é capturada? Você captura a exceção e faz nada com ela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro apresente os possíveis erros ou exceptions para serem exibidos:

No seu método QueryInsert use `errorInfo()` e `$ex->getMessage()`

```
public function queryInsert($dados) {

        try {
            $this->login = $dados['login'];
            $this->senha = sha1($dados['senha']);
            $this->email = $dados['email'];
            $this->rrname = $dados['rrname'];

            $cst = $this->con->conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO 'contas' ('login', 'senha', 'email', 'nomenorr') VALUES (:login, :senha, :email, :rrname)");
            $cst->bindParam(':login', $this->login);
            $cst->bindParam(':senha', $this->senha);
            $cst->bindParam(':email', $this->email);
            $cst->bindParam(':rrname', $this->rrname);                      

            if ($cst->execute()) {               
                return 'sucess';
            } else { 
                var_dump($cst->errorInfo());            
            }
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Outro possível cenário, dependendo do local e nomenclatura, o seu código pode estar usando o header para a classe Cadastro e desse modo não apresenta nenhum resultado, mesmo que vc coloque para exibir os erros ou exceptions comente o `header("location: ./cadastro.php");`

```
require_once '/src/domain/conta.php';
$Cad = new Cadastro();

if (isset($_POST['btCad'])) {

    $dados = $_POST;   

    if ($Cad->queryInsert($dados) == 'success') {
       header("location: ./index.php");
    } else {
       //header("location: ./cadastro.php");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom o seu Action está vazio, mais se vc ajustar e ele continuar sem resultado, provavelmente é erro no MYSQL, um jeito de ver isso é pegar o código do MySQL e testar no próprio banco, se lá funcionar e na aplicação continuar sem acontecer nada, é bem provável que o campo: emails,senha, etc... Esteja passando valores vazios, e se sua tabela não aceitar vazio "NOT NULL"', vai dar erro no banco!

Comment: Não precisa de nada no action, a ação ta sendo feita no php da página, e eu testei o banco e está funcionando :/, os dados que estão sendo escritos nos campos estão aparecendo no echo